# Get VBScript Output result in Batch Script and use it in another place

Tags: vbscript, spring-batch

I have a VBScript which list drives' letters. I want to get the drives' letters in a batch script and use it somewhere. For example think the output of VBScript is "C:\;D:\;F:\", then I want to tell batch script to get this info remove C:\ from it and write D:\;F:\ in a text file. I want to do it only via batch script.

Here is a VBScript for a example:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

drives = ""
For Each objDisk in colDisks
  if drives > "" then
    drives = drives & chr(13)
  end if
  drives = drives & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
Next
```

So How to do that?
Thanks,
Majid Pasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works for you but you can execute the batch file from the vb script and pass the list of drives as a parameter.

Example VB Sript:

```
dim sh
dim drives
drives = "C:\;D:\;F:\"
set sh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
sh.run "test.bat " & Chr(34) & drives & Chr(34)
```

And you can test it by creating the file test.bat as:

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
```

Otherwise, if it has to be the batch file that kicks it off, you can start the vb script with the `Start` command, but not sure how you return a value to the batch file so the only way I can think of right now would be for the vb script to write the drives to a file using the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx) (FSO) and then you can read that in the batch file using code similar to:

```
start c:\test.vbs 
set /p drives= < test.txt
echo %drives%
pause
```

The documentation I link to for FSO includes a very simple sample for writing to a text file.